Issue Connecting to A100 GPU in Google Colab Pro
I paid for the Colab Pro service for the first time on July 17, 2024. Since then, I have used the platform no more than 3 or 4 times trying to create content. Today, when I tried to connect again to the A100 GPU that I need, it wouldn't let me. I would like to know how many compute units are consumed with each use because I have used it very little.
The message displayed is: "Want access to premium GPUs? You have subscribed to Pro, but you don't have any compute units available. Purchase additional compute units."
I have recently paid, and it seems crazy to me that I cannot access the A100 GPU. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a service issue?
I have tried looking into different blogs to see if anyone has the answer about how many compute units are equivalent to usage. The most similar information I found was on Reddit, where someone said: "I can only tell you for the two types that I use. TPU's and T4's with regular memory are roughly 2 compute units per hour. So that's roughly 50 hours of computing on those, the more expensive GPU's deplete much higher but I don't know the metrics on those since for that stuff I use other services." This was a year ago, but I have not used 100 hours of anything.
